# removing the semicolon from json output

Tags: php, drupal

I have a `$object` which reads from json objects. I am using `_filter_url()` function to display the text as url in drupal.

Whenever there are more than 1 urls, it displays the semicolon at the end of the 1st url. How do i remove that? Meaning I want the urls as well as the semicolon without a hyperlink under it.

```
function test($object){
    echo str_replace('; ','',$object);  //this removes the ;   but I need the semicolon also to be    displayed without any hyperlink below it. 
}

function test($object) {
    $x = explode(';',$object);
    for($i=0;$i<count($x);$i++) {
        echo _filter_url($x[$i]);   //even this removes the semicolon, but i want the semicolon to be    displayed at the middle of multiple urls, however the semicolon should not have the hyperlink under
    }
}
```

The output thatI get is :

> url1
>   url2   each url is on separate line

The desired output is :

> url1 ;
>   url2

**I need a semicolon between multiple urls**.
However this semicolon should not be part of the hyperlink

Comment: The use of $object in your example code and in the description makes this harder to understand (since it's seemingly about a string). You should show us the expected input, and the wrong output plus what you actually wanted to have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
trim($object, '; ');
```

See http://ch2.php.net/trim, this will remove ' ' and ';' only from the start or end of the string.

Also note that $bject is probably the crappiest variable name you could have come up with if it is actually a string.